# MySQL query to display periods between dates

Tags: mysql

In my table, I have two separate date fields, X and Y.  In Field x I have the date of 13/08/2008 and in field Y I have the date of 13/08/2015.

I was wondering if there is a sql way working out what the six monthly date periods are between field X and Y, having the results displayed on separate lines?  So, I was hoping to have the following results in two fields:

```
BEGIN     | END
13-Aug-08 | 13-Feb-09
13-Feb-09 | 13-Aug-09
13-Aug-09 | 15-Feb-10
15-Feb-10 | 13-Aug-10
13-Aug-10 | 14-Feb-11
14-Feb-11 | 15-Aug-11
15-Aug-11 | 13-Feb-12
13-Feb-12 | 13-Aug-12
13-Aug-12 | 13-Feb-13
13-Feb-13 | 13-Aug-13
13-Aug-13 | 13-Feb-14
13-Feb-14 | 13-Aug-14
13-Aug-14 | 13-Feb-15
13-Feb-15 | 13-Aug-15
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
DATE '2006-05-20' + INTERVAL 5 DAY   -> DATE '2006-05-25' 
DATE '2006-05-20' + INTERVAL 5 MONTH -> DATE '2006-10-20' 
DATE '2006-05-20' + INTERVAL 5 YEAR  -> DATE '2011-05-20'
```

---

**Example 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE BEGIN_DATES
(
     BDates DATETIME
); 

INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2008'); 
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/02/2009');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2009');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('15/02/2010');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2010');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('14/02/2011');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('15/08/2011');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/02/2012');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2012');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/02/2013');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2013');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/02/2014');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/08/2014');
INSERT INTO BEGIN_DATES VALUE ('13/02/2015');


SELECT BDates AS BEGIN, (BDates + INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS END
FROM BEGIN_DATES

DROP TABLE BEGIN_DATES
```

---

**Eample 2:**

```
BEGIN
SET @date = '2008-08-13';
SET @Edate ='2015-08-13';

WHILE @date <= @Edate DO

SELECT @date AS BEGIN_DATE, CAST(@date AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 6 MONTH AS END_DATE;  -- ADDDATE(@date,INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

SET @date = CAST(@date AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 6 MONTH;   -- Or ADDDATE(@date,INTERVAL 6 MONTH)

END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: Thanks. But that would mean I would have to know what the begin dates are before I could do an insert into. I'm hoping there is a more dynamic approach whereby MySQL could work out for me what the six monthly dates are from date X. I have to then apply this logic to a table containing over 110k records with differing date X's.

Comment: You can take a dynamic approach using this method: **SELECT CURDATE() AS BEGIN, (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 MONTH)**

Comment: You can place it in a while loop

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, how would that look in terms of code?  While loop would that be in a stored procedure, or can you include a while loop in a select statement?

Comment: Please the update to my answer and also feel free to check my answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Presumbly this goes in a stored procedure? Is there a way of having this run as a select query to see if it creates the results I'm looking for.  If it works I think I can then do a insert into statement to pull the records into a new table, where I can then do extra processing on them.

Comment: I get an error that says subquery returns more than 1 row. I put the above into a stored procedure.

Comment: No, example 2 is not working.  Just keeps looping on the first record.